# sql query for the following statement?

Tags: sql

My table 'Customer' contains customerid , firstname, lastname, company,city,state,country, email, invoicetotal

Question: For countries that have at least two customers using yahoo as email provider, display the name alongside the revenue

My solution:

```
select county,sum(invoiceTotal)from customer where email like '%yahoo%'
group by Country,Email having Count(Country)>2
```

I am unable to get proper result the no of rows displayed in my output are different from the number of rows in expected output,Can any1 tell me where have i gone wrong???

Comment: you should only group by the country, if you group by the email you'll get a group for each email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping by `email` as well - just group by `Country` and you should be fine

```
select 
    county,
    sum(invoiceTotal)
from customer 
where email like '%yahoo%'
group by Country
having Count(Country)>2
```

Comment: a slight change in ur code, having Count(Country)>=2 as its written atleast, and thnx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

You can't group by `email`, since that's unique. Fortunately, you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    county,
    sum(invoiceTotal)
from customer 
where email like '%yahoo%'
group by Country
having Count(Country)>=2
```

Because the statement say *at least* then you need put `>=`.